drafting your own provisional patent, then hire attorney to review and submit
I am writing a software patent application.
I am wondering if the following strategy is feasible:

draft your own provisional patent
hire attorney to review and submit
hire attorney to draft the non-provisional

I believe that I can draft the specifications and the drawings myself. So I just need the attorney to draft claims, basically.
Will this work?

Unlikely. Protecting software innovations is getting harder and harder and has become a somewhat specialized art.
Getting someone to review and file something written by a person without extensive patent knowledge and experience will be hard to accomplish. Wording from inexperienced clients in the form of a draft specification generally has little value as contributing to actual text to be filed.
Patent work requires precision. As an example - there is no such thing as a provisional patent. Only provisional patent applications.

I actually have some software patents and I wouldn’t dream of trying to draft the specification myself. The specification enables the claims. Good attorneys often draft the claims first. In any case I sincerely doubt you can find an attorney willing to just draft the claims.
Now writing your own draft spec can be helpful in communicating your invention to the attorney which might reduce billing some. Just don’t be surprised if little is actually used verbatim.
